# How to read out a #define macro in C?

Tags: arrays, c, macros

I am unexperienced in C and have a question.
I wanted to ask how to read the hexadecimal numbers out and get into an array

```
#define configMAC_ADDR                \
{                                      \
    0x02, 0x12, 0x13, 0x10, 0x15, 0x11  \
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro is the same as writing `{ 0x02, 0x12, 0x13, 0x10, 0x15, 0x11 }`. So where you would have normally written that initializer list in your source code, write `configMAC_ADDR` instead. It's just text replacement in this case.

---

The `\` symbol can appear anywhere in C code and means source code line break. You can use it to break up a long line of code into several and have the compiler treat them as a single line still, so it is commonly used for macros. Without it you'd have to write the macro as:

```
#define configMAC_ADDR { 0x02, 0x12, 0x13, 0x10, 0x15, 0x11 }
```

Which is 100% equivalent but in some cases less readable.

Comment: ... and "initializer list" is definitely the right term.  The macro's replacement text cannot be regarded as representing an array, though it could be used to initialize one.

Comment: Yep... the advanced task of initializing an array of integers and then replace the initializer list with a single word is purposely left to the reader as exercise.